# Proving something is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis

Given the following function:  $$x\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)$$

How do I show that this is uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$?

The reason why I am having trouble is that I am use to finding pathologies in functions which causes them to not have a certain property.

Furthermore, is there a more "analysis" like way of doing this.

(1)  $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$

(2)  L'Hospital's Rule:  $\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$.  Taking all appropriate limits I get $1$.

This is about where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $-x \le x \sin (x^{-1}) \le x$, your function has a limit at 0, namely $0$, so we may extend it to a continuous function $f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$, which is uniformly continuous on $[0,2]$ (as this is a compact interval) and on $[1,\infty)$ (as $f$ has bounded derivative 
\[
 f'(x) = \sin\left(\frac 1x\right) - \frac{\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)}{x} 
\]
here and is therefore Lipschitz). Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$, hence on $(0,\infty)$.